# css before & after vertical alignment top

Tags: css, shapes, pseudo-element

[image: enlarged to make it eaiser to see misalignment]

I have a simple slider in which I am making two arrows on either end for. 
However the alignment of the arrows on either end is off by one pixel. It's either lower or higher in both firefox and chrome by one pixel. I am creating the arrows in css. I am using osx 10 mountain lion, not windows.

I have setup a codepen here:
http://cdpn.io/mevrI

Any thoughts on how to have them align to the same top position?

Thanks,
Bart

Comment: looks good on my computer (chrome & FF). Try a hard refresh on your browser?

Comment: I am on a mac osx 10 moutain lion, what os are you on?

Comment: Windows XP, Chrome 27, FF 21

Comment: Ok that is good to know, thanks for letting know.

Comment: This brings up a couple of questions. (1) Is there a 1px difference in rendering a absolute-block within a relative-block between mac and pc platforms for similar browsers and (2) does this difference manifest itself only in the context of pseudo-elements?

Comment: As a hunch, can you set the `line-height: 15px` the parent element and the two pseudo-elements? I am thinking it may have to do with default baseline computations.

Comment: I will give the line height a shot. It appears that does not work either...

Comment: I was hoping... would it be too much trouble to post a screen show showing us what you see on your mac?

Comment: I just posted a picture of the problem

Comment: Using firefox on MacOS I see the same thing you did.  I can't explain why it behaves like this. When I set both left and right borders on the before pseudo element, they don't line up either.  But when I change the border size from 5px to 6px, the magic happens and they line up.  Almost like there is a round-off error somewhere.  Go figure.

Answer (score 0):

it would be much easier to use 'letters symbol' in hex format and vertical-align them with line-height :)

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/fcAji

```
.handle {
  width: 110px;
  height: 15px;
  cursor: move;
  position: relative;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  margin-left: -1px;
  z-index: 100; 
  background-color:#00718E;
  line-height: 15px;
  font-size:15px;
}

.handle:before {
  content:"\25C0";
  position:absolute;
  top:0;
  left:3px;
  line-height: 15px;
  color:white;
}

.handle:after {
 transparent; 
  content:"\25B6";
  position:absolute;
  top:0;
  right:3px;
  line-height: 15px;
  color:white;
}
```

unless you do not want to use characters .

Comment: some more characters to test and use http://www.alanwood.net/unicode/geometric_shapes.html

Comment: It is still not aligned in the codepen for me on OSX mountain lion